# How to convert excel column with json format data to a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json, excel, parsing, csvtojson

I have an excel sheet with a column that has data in json format. I want to convert this sheet into json. The other two columns get converted into json but this particular column cannot be treated as a json object and instead results into a string. JSON.parse() does not work on this string and throws a Syntax Error. Here are the things I have tried:

- Convert excel sheet to json using xlsx package
- Convert excel to csv to json using csvtojson package

Neither helped me successfully convert the last column into a json object
Below is my code:

```
let xlsx = require("xlsx")
const csvtojson = require("csvtojson")
let path = require("path")
let fs = require("fs");

const inputFilePath = path.join(__dirname, './mastersheet.xlsx');
let File = xlsx.readFile(inputFilePath);
let content = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_csv(File.Sheets['Sheet6']);

fs.writeFile('./mastersheet.csv', content, (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err)
})

csvtojson()
    .fromFile('./mastersheet.csv')
    .then((jsonObj) => {
         console.log(jsonObj);
         fs.writeFileSync("mastersheet.json", JSON.stringify(validJsonData), 'utf8', (err) => {
             if (err) console.log(err);
         })
    });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [convert-excel-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-excel-to-json) and you convert excel to json like this:

```
const excelToJson = require('convert-excel-to-json');
const fs = require('fs');

const result = excelToJson({
    source: fs.readFileSync('exlTest.xlsx'),
    header:{
        rows: 1
    }
});
console.log('result :', result);
```

Comment: Converting it to json is not the issue. Converting excel data that is already in json format causes problems as it cannot be parsed as json in javascript